# Android : Why onTextChanged() Execute when Activity wants to create?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use onTextChanged() in my activity for one of my EditText , but it execute when the page is creating and because I use Text of EditText to calculate parameters, I have Error and force close app.

```
final TextView TextView_Tax = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_Tax);

    EditText_Qty_Ordering.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (TaxA > 0 & TaxM > 0) {

                    String value = String.valueOf((((TaxA + TaxM) / 100) * SalesPrice) * (Integer.parseInt(EditText_Qty_Ordering.getText().toString())));
                    TextView_Tax.setText(value);



        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



        }
    });
```

Comment: Posting code here will help you better. As using text from EditText is posting force close is resulting due to crash ( can imaging it would be some null pointer exception)

Comment: Because the EditText has to be initialized with some value in the first place

Comment: By saying page do you mean the Activity?

Comment: Yes Activity means.